# Distribution of the $l_2$-norm of gaussian vector

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $Y_k \sim N(\mu_k, \sigma_k^2)$. For $\sigma_k = \sigma$ the squared norm of $Y = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$ follows the [noncentral chi square distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).

What is the distribution in the general case? The derivation of the pdf found on wikipedia doesn't generalize to our case.

Comment: Rewrite $$Y= \sigma_1 \cdot\sigma_2\cdots\sigma_n(Y_1/\sigma_1,\dots,Y_n/\sigma_n).$$

Comment: I don't see the equality, sorry. Your right hand side is $N(\mu, \sigma^2*I)$-distributed, where $\sigma = \sigma_1 * \ldots * \sigma_n$ and $I$ is the identiy matrix, while the left hand side is not.

Comment: Think about that better. First, consider $(Y_1/ \sigma_1,\dots,Y_n /\sigma_n).$

Comment: You are right. See the complicated and nested formulas for PDFs obtained with Maple in the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/3822990309/PDF.pdf).

Comment: That's a pity :(  Thanks!